# Data manipulation with gsub

Tags: r

I have a variable which has character values like "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)"

After using below set of codes I am getting output as "Mrs" alone

```
gsub("[.,(,,)]",'',a$V1)

gsub('(.*,)|(\\..*)','',a$V1)
```

Please help me in understanding above codes, what it does exactly?

Comment: You need to learn regular expressions. [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) is a great reference. I've linked the page specific to R.

Comment: You might also look at the documentation here on Stack Overflow - [Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/5748/regular-expressions-regex#t=201706041200011156533)

Comment: Thank you, ll go through the site and come back if any.

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern of `gsub` is the following:
`gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ...)`.

`pattern` is the string you want to be replaced.

`replacement`is what you want to replace your `pattern` for.

`x`is the object where you wish to apply your replacements.

In your case, the first `gsub`function you posted will replace the pattern `"[.,(,,)]"`, by the pattern `''` and this replacement will be applied on `a$V1`

```
> # considering the following data frame
> df <- df <- data.frame(color = c("green", "yellow", "blue"), shape=c("squared", "triangle", "octagon"))
> df
   color    shape
1  green  squared
2 yellow triangle
3   blue  octagon
> # Let's say you want to replace, under df$color the string "green" by "purple", you could run the following command:
> df_new <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub(pattern = "green", replacement = "purple", df$color)}))
> # which gives you:
> df_new
   color  shape
1 purple purple
2 yellow yellow
3   blue   blue
```

When working with data frames (I see that this is you case because of your `x (a$V1)` keep in mind to wrap the `gsub`function within lapply. Otherwise the ouptput can get quite messy.